# Can I cast Dire Fleet Daredevil if my opponent has no instants or sorceries in their graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I want to cast [Dire Fleet Daredevil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDire%20Fleet%20Daredevil%5d) but my opponent has no instants or sorceries in their graveyard.

Am I able to cast it?

The text doesn't read "You **may** exile target instant or sorcery", but it also doesn't require it as an additional cost.

Comment: As a side note, one of the "skill tests" that separate novice players from experienced players is that, on the whole, novice players assume that because such text exist on the card, that you should wait until you can use it effectively. An experienced player loves to benefit from the card, but sometimes you just need a body on the battlefield (and honestly, a 2 power FS for 2 is not terrible, especially in an environment full of 4/2s.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, you may cast [Dire Fleet Daredevil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDire%20Fleet%20Daredevil%5d) if you opponent has no instant or sorcerys in their graveyard.**

When your Dire Fleet Daredevil enters the battlefield, it will try to do as much as possible with what is available to it. Unfortunately for you since there is no instant or sorcery in your opponent's graveyard you will be unable to cast an instant or sorcery from your opponent's graveyard. You will still however have your creature. This is according to the [CR](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Triggered_ability)(emphasis mine):

> **603.3d**: The remainder of the process for putting a triggered ability on the stack is identical to the process for casting a spell listed in rules 601.2c–d. **If a choice is required when the triggered ability goes on the stack but no legal choices can be made for it**, or if a rule or a continuous effect otherwise makes the ability illegal, **the ability is simply removed from the stack.**

The confusion in your question seem to stem from thinking of Dire Fleet's ability as an [additional cost](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Additional_cost). Additional cost must be paid in order to cast a spell if they do not contain "may". A good way to recognize additional costs is to look for the phrase "As an additional cost to cast..."

Comment: I suggest distinguishing this from [*additional costs*](https://scryfall.com/search?q=re%3A%22additional+cost*exile%22&order=set), such as on Makeshift Mauler and Relentless Skaabs: it's a different ability which happens later, after the creature is cast, then fails. It would have to be an additional cost to prevent DFD from being cast, because it would be a cost you have to be able to pay before casting the spell.

Comment: @ikegami in this case as much as possible is nothing at all, since there is no valid targets

Comment: This answer is wrong. As Ikegami says; the ability will never resolve; without legal targets it can't remain on the stack.

Comment: "The confusion in your question seem to stem from thinking of Dire Fleet's ability as an additional cost." I think the confusion seems to stem more from thinking that choosing targets is something you would do when you cast the creature, as opposed to something you would do after the creature resolves, when dealing with the triggered ability.

Comment: @GendoIkari @ ikegami @ Dopplegreener, I have read through the CR a bit more and picked changed the cited CR

Comment: Yes, after I started writing the comment. But even with the word effect removed, it's not any better. Creatures don't "try to do as much as possible". Creatures don't do anything at all. /// It is also wrong to claim "you will be unable to cast an instant or sorcery from your opponent's graveyard", since you will never be asked to cast an instant or sorcery from your opponent's graveyard. /// Finally, you forgot to demonstrate that a choice is required (by 601.2c). It's not clear that the OP knows targets are picked when the ability is placed on the stack (and not on resolution).

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can.

The enter-the-battlefield ability has nothing to do with casting the creature itself. Creatures are not targeted spells. If they have an enter-the-battlefield trigger, then that ability will trigger after you have cast the creature spell and after it resolves.

After you cast Dire Fleet Daredevil and it resolves, its enter the battlefield ability will trigger. At this point, you must chose targets for the triggered ability, and if you can't do so, then the ability simply disappears:

> 603.3d The remainder of the process for putting a triggered ability on the stack is identical to the process for casting a spell listed in rules 601.2c–d. **If a choice is required when the triggered ability goes on the stack but no legal choices can be made for it, or if a rule or a continuous effect otherwise makes the ability illegal, the ability is simply removed from the stack.**
>
> 601.2c The player announces his or her choice of an appropriate player, object, or zone for each target the spell requires. [...]

Comment: "After you cast Dire Fleet Daredevil, its enter the battlefield ability will trigger." - perhaps you should change your wording here, novice players might interpret this with an "immediately" in there.

Comment: @Hamsterrific Good catch.